# Image/Bitmap placement?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Have any of you seen the simulator bong apps in android? How would you make that app? For example I have tried doing it using xml layouts. I divided the picture up and placed it in order and in segments so that when a particular picture is pressed a function will occur. Problem is that on different phones the size of the collective pictures either extends off the screen or is compressed.

I have also tried using surfaceViews with bitmaps so that each individual picture can take the size of the screen and adjust them accordingly. I am having trouble making the pictures not plop on top of eachother and instead be placed in order going down the screen. I can get the first 2 just fine designating the Rect dst with the starting height being where the other ended but the third and fourth aren't showing up on the screen. For example I used

```
Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight/7 );
```

For the first image which is on the top. Then for the second image

```
Rect dst = new Rect(0, mHeight/7, mWidth, mHeight/3 );
```

(mHeight and mWidth is the canvas width and height)

Not sure how to go about placing the next 2 pictures beneath them and eachother. I tried

```
Rect dst = new Rect(0, mHeight/7+(mHeight/3), mWidth, mHeight/7);
```

That didn't work though. It honestly looks really simple to do and I'm sure it is, but I just cant seem to get the images to work the way I want. Is there a way to leave the image as a whole and specify when a certain spot is selected it does something (that would work on every phone the same way).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Any other ideas for how to get the result I want are also very much appreciated. Thanks for taking time to read this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could divide the screen into regions like left,top,width,height.
Eg.
Region 1 (0,50,100,100)
Region 2 (100,50,100,100).

And add a OnTouchListener and use that to get touch coords and check which region it belongs to. I'm not sure if it a good way but it is doable.

Comment: Thanks that's an excellent recommendation. Do  you think it will match up with the picture on each phone correctly though?

Comment: Well you'll have to use different size images and place it in the different drawable folders. If you only keep one copy in the drawable-ldpi, then that image will be automatically scaled in larger phones.